# SQL can't insert data for time dimension table

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am building a Data warehouse for my school project. I have already created my time dimension table and it works.

```
`  CREATE TABLE TimeDim(
   [timeCode] int primary key,
   [date] datetime,
   [year] char(4),
   [month] varchar(2),
   [monthName] varchar(9),
   [Quarter] varchar(9),
   [dayOfMonth] varchar(2),
   [dayName] varchar(9),
   [dayOfQuarter] varchar(3),
   [dayOfYear] varchar(3),
   [weekOfMonth] varchar(1),
   [weekOfQuarter] varchar(2),
   [weekOfYear] varchar(2));`
```

However, the errors occur when I try to create data in the Time Dimension table.The error shows: **

```
`Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 95
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.`
```

**
The code for me to create data is

```
 DECLARE @StartDate DATETIME = '01/01/2003' --Starting value of Date Range
DECLARE @EndDate DATETIME = '01/01/2006' --End Value of Date Range ( end at 31/12/1999)

--Temporary Variables To Hold the Values During Processing of Each Date of Year
DECLARE
    @DayOfWeekInMonth INT,
    @DayOfWeekInYear INT,
    @DayOfQuarter INT,
    @WeekOfMonth INT,
    @CurrentYear INT,
    @CurrentMonth INT,
    @CurrentQuarter INT

/*Table Data type to store the day of week count for the month and year*/
DECLARE @DayOfWeek TABLE (DOW INT, MonthCount INT, QuarterCount INT, YearCount INT)

INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (1, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (2, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (3, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (4, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (5, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (6, 0, 0, 0)
INSERT INTO @DayOfWeek VALUES (7, 0, 0, 0)

--Extract and assign various parts of Values from Current Date to Variable

DECLARE @CurrentDate AS DATETIME = @StartDate
SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)

/********************************************************************************************/
--Proceed only if Start Date(Current date ) is less than End date you specified above

WHILE @CurrentDate < @EndDate
BEGIN

/*Begin day of week logic*/

         /*Check for Change in Month of the Current date if Month changed then 
          Change variable value*/
    IF @CurrentMonth != DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) 
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET MonthCount = 0
        SET @CurrentMonth = DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)
    END

        /* Check for Change in Quarter of the Current date if Quarter changed then change 
         Variable value*/

    IF @CurrentQuarter != DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET QuarterCount = 0
        SET @CurrentQuarter = DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate)
    END

        /* Check for Change in Year of the Current date if Year changed then change 
         Variable value*/


    IF @CurrentYear != DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
    BEGIN
        UPDATE @DayOfWeek
        SET YearCount = 0
        SET @CurrentYear = DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate)
    END

        -- Set values in table data type created above from variables 

    UPDATE @DayOfWeek
    SET 
        MonthCount = MonthCount + 1,
        QuarterCount = QuarterCount + 1,
        YearCount = YearCount + 1
    WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)

    SELECT
        @DayOfWeekInMonth = MonthCount,
        @DayOfQuarter = QuarterCount,
        @DayOfWeekInYear = YearCount
    FROM @DayOfWeek
    WHERE DOW = DATEPART(DW, @CurrentDate)

/*End day of week logic*/


/* Populate Your Dimension Table with values*/

    INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeDim]
    SELECT

        CONVERT (char(8),@CurrentDate,112) as timeCode,
        @CurrentDate AS date,
        CONVERT (char(10),@CurrentDate,103) as FullDateUK,
        CONVERT (char(10),@CurrentDate,101) as FullDateUSA,
        DATEPART(DD, @CurrentDate) AS dayOfMonth,
        --Apply Suffix values like 1st, 2nd 3rd etc..   
        DATENAME(DW, @CurrentDate) AS dayName,  
        @DayOfQuarter AS dayOfQuarter,
        DATEPART(DY, @CurrentDate) AS dayOfYear,
        DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) + 1 - DATEPART(WW, CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
        DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate)) + '/1/' + CONVERT(VARCHAR, 
        DATEPART(YY, @CurrentDate))) AS weekOfMonth,
        (DATEDIFF(DD, DATEADD(QQ, DATEDIFF(QQ, 0, @CurrentDate), 0), 
        @CurrentDate) / 7) + 1 AS weekOfQuarter,
        DATEPART(WW, @CurrentDate) AS weekOfYear,
        DATEPART(MM, @CurrentDate) AS month,
        DATENAME(MM, @CurrentDate) AS monthName,

        DATEPART(QQ, @CurrentDate) AS Quarter,

        DATEPART(YEAR, @CurrentDate) AS year


    SET @CurrentDate = DATEADD(DD, 1, @CurrentDate)
END
```

Comment: You are trying to `insert` many more columns than your table has. For instance, the column `FullDateUK` is not available in your table, and likewise many more attributes.

Comment: When you insert a row in your table, the sequence of field in your INSERT statement must match the sequence of fields in the table.  Just aliasing your fields in the insert statement is not enough for the database to figure out where to put your values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Error is so clear:-

> Column name or number of supplied values does not match table
>   definition.

That means you trying insert number of values doesn't match with number of columns.

**The number of Columns** is **13**, as next:-

1. timeCode
2. date
3. year
4. month
5. monthName
6. Quarter
7. dayOfMonth
8. dayName
9. dayOfQuarter
10. dayOfYear
11. weekOfMonth
12. weekOfQuarter
13. weekOfYear

**The number of values** is **36**, as following:-

1. TimeKey
2. Date
3. FullDateUK
4. FullDateUSA
5. DayOfMonth
6. DaySuffix
7. DayName
8. DayOfWeekUSA
9. DayOfWeekUK
10. DayOfWeekInMonth
11. DayOfWeekInYear
12. DayOfQuarter
13. DayOfYear
14. WeekOfMonth
15. WeekOfQuarter
16. WeekOfYear
17. Month
18. MonthName
19. MonthOfQuarter
20. Quarter
21. QuarterName
22. Year
23. YearName
24. MonthYear
25. MMYYYY
26. FirstDayOfMonth
27. LastDayOfMonth
28. FirstDayOfQuarter
29. LastDayOfQuarter
30. FirstDayOfYear
31. LastDayOfYear
32. IsHolidayUSA
33. IsWeekday
34. HolidayUSA
35. (No column name)
36. (No column name)

### UPDATE:-

After Editing the script , the error still existing, because the number of values is **15** as following:-

1. timeCode
2. date
3. FullDateUK
4. FullDateUSA
5. dayOfMonth
6. dayName
7. dayOfQuarter
8. dayOfYear
9. weekOfMonth
10. weekOfQuarter
11. weekOfYear
12. month
13. monthName
14. Quarter
15. year

Comment: I have modified my script on top and it still shows the error, which is "Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 95
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition." Line 95 is "INSERT INTO [dbo].[TimeDim]".

Comment: @xhinvis Glad to help you.